# Is there any way to order the foreground paint-update on graphics view?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

Graphicsview paints first the background, then the layer and last the foreground.
I'd like to use the foreground to draw some dynamic things over the main geometric information, but I dont know how to send an update order only for the foreground.
Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: I answer myself:
G_scene->invalidate(QRect(),QGraphicsScene::ForegroundLayer); Excuse me ....

Comment: It's fine to post your own answer as a proper answer and then mark it as solved, then people with the same problem can see you found a solution easily.

Comment: Note also, it's not really a useful answer - at this point (Qt 4.8) Qt does no optimization for foreground-only invalidation - it repaints the whole thing.